# How full config ie affects pdcp sn during handover in lte

Tags: lte

I would like to inquire how full configuration during handover affects retransmission of pdcp(sn) and pdcp (no sn).
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Related information is captured in 3GPP RRC specification(36.331) in section titled as "Radio Configuration involving full configuration option" (section 5.3.5.8).

You will find that full configuration option includes an initialization of the radio configuration, which makes the procedure independent of the configuration used in the source cell(s) with the exception that the security algorithms are continued for the RRC re-establishment.

For reconfigurations involving the full configuration option, the PDCP entities are newly established (SN and HFN do not continue) for all DRBs irrespective of the RLC mode. Check PDCP specification(36.323) for related details.